# Regex - Greedyness - matching HTML tags, content and attributes

Tags: php, html, regex, greedy, regex-greedy

I am trying to match specific span-tags from an HTML source.

The lang-attribute and the inner HTML of the tag are used as parameters for a function which returns a new string.

I want replace the old tags, attributes and content with the result of the called function.

The subject would be something like this:

```
<p>Some codesnippet:</p>
<span lang="fsharp">// PE001
let p001 = [0..999]
           |> List.filter (fun n -> n % 3 = 0 || n % 5 = 0)
           |> List.sum
</span>
<p>Another code snippet:</p>
<span lang="C#">//C# testclass
class MyClass {
}
</span>
```

In order to extract the value of the lang attribute and the content, I group those values with the following expression:

```
/(<span lang="(.*)">(.*)</span>)/is
```

Since regex tends to be greedy, This expression matches the complete subject, not just one span-tag and its content.

How do i manage to match just one span-tag?

Comment: For manipulating html markup you're far better off using the right tool for the job.  PHP provides you with DOMDocument, which is built for the task.  Tehre's also XMLReader and SimpleXML. While they're less suitable they can still handle XHTML quite nicely.

Comment: I think you need to back up a step and ask, *Is this a sensible use of the `lang` attribute?*  Or, *Should I be trying to embed code in HTML like this?*

Comment: This implies you have a better idea of solving the task - please explain and share your thoughts! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We'll never reapeat it again : **do not use regular expressions to work with HTML !**

Instead, use [**`DOMDocument::loadHTML`**][1].

It'll allow you to manipulate your HTML data using the DOM, which is much more powerful and easier : you'll be able to :

- Use methods such as [`getElementById`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementbyid.php) and [`getElementsByTagName`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php) for simple extractions,
- Use the [**`DOMXPath`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) class to make XPath queries on your document
- Work with [**`DOMElement`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domelement.php)s, and methods such as [`getAttribute`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domelement.getattribute.php) / [`setAttribute`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domelement.setattribute.php)
- ...

Really : take the time to learn DOM : it's a great investment !

Comment: ... yeah, and don't forget to learn to use HTML Tidy, 'cause DOMDocument will fail to work with invalid HTML

Comment: Thank you! I didn't even know PHP provides DOM handlers ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can specify it to be ungreedy using `?`

`/(<span lang="(.*?)">(.*?)<\/span>)/is`

or make all expression ungreedy by default using [PCRE_UNGREEDY modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php#reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers)

`/(<span lang="(.*)">(.*)<\/span>)/Uis`

Answer (score 1):

Just adding **?** , I think

```
/(<span lang="(.*?)">(.*?)</span>)/is
```