# how to write regular expression for this by php?

Tags: php, regex, html-parsing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Regex - Greedyness - matching HTML tags, content and attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272604/regex-greedyness-matching-html-tags-content-and-attributes)

The text I want to parse is something like this:

```
Dir: <a href="/name/nm0381817/">Vinton Heuck</a>, <a href="/name/nm1367649/">Ciro Nieli</a>
    With: <a href="/name/nm0519680/">Eric Loomis</a>, <a href="/name/nm0732436/">Bumper Robinson</a>, <a href="/name/nm1685408/">Dawn Olivieri</a>
```

Usually, there're one or two anchor elements after "Dir" and multiple anchor elements after "With".

What I want to do is get all values of anchor elements after "Dir" and before "With". I tried some regular expression like this:

```
preg_match_all("/Dir: <a href=\"\/name\/.+\/\">(.+)<\/a>/", $content, $matches);
```

But this only works when there's only one anchor element after "Dir". Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Fey, when you say it "only works when there's only one anchor element", what happens when it you have more? (does it return everything? nothing?)

Answer (score 0):

i think you are missing some grouping instruction "()+" to get not only one but one or two links, take a look at [this](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) to test your regex.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to group your regex for finding the anchor tag, and use + for one or more.

Something like:

```
/Dir: (<a href=\"\/name\/.+\/\">(.+)<\/a>)+/
```

You'd have to edit to take into account the comma, but it will get you started.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the line that contains "Dir:" appears only once:

```
preg_match_all("/(<([[:graph:]]+)[^>]*>)(.*?)(<\/\\2>)/", preg_replace("/[[:blank:]]*With:.*/","",$content), $matches);

print_r($matches[3]);
```